# Understanding of WMI process killing script

Tags: vbscript

I found this script on your site. I am still very new to VB, I would like to see if someone could explain this script to me. I need to know where to enter the process and what this is doing.

```
Sub KillProc( myProcess )
'Authors: Denis St-Pierre and Rob van der Woude
'Purpose: Kills a process and waits until it is truly dead

    Dim blnRunning, colProcesses, objProcess
    blnRunning = False

    Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                       "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                       ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process", , 48 )
    For Each objProcess in colProcesses
        If LCase( myProcess ) = LCase( objProcess.Name ) Then
            ' Confirm that the process was actually running
            blnRunning = True
            ' Get exact case for the actual process name
            myProcess  = objProcess.Name
            ' Kill all instances of the process
            objProcess.Terminate()
        End If
    Next

    If blnRunning Then
        ' Wait and make sure the process is terminated.
        ' Routine written by Denis St-Pierre.
        Do Until Not blnRunning
            Set colProcesses = GetObject( _
                        "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}" _
                        ).ExecQuery( "Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = '" _
                        & myProcess & "'" )
            WScript.Sleep 100 'Wait for 100 MilliSeconds
            If colProcesses.Count = 0 Then 'If no more processes are running, exit loop
                blnRunning = False
            End If
        Loop
        ' Display a message
        WScript.Echo myProcess & " was terminated"
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Process """ & myProcess & """ not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand? If *none* of it, then there are plenty of basic WMI references findable via Google.  If there's some specific part which is giving you problems then you should specify which lines.

Comment: Tim, Its more less where to enter the process I want to kill. Under what part of the code would the process name go under?

Comment: `myProcess` is the name of the process you want to kill.  It's designed to be called as a sub-procedure.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. What if I want to have multiple process's? Would it a a simple ("Access" or "Calc")

Comment: Just call it once for each process you want to kill.